# Using and understanding MATLAB's TreeBagger (a random forest) method

Tags: matlab, tree, random-forest

I'm trying to use MATLAB's TreeBagger method, which implements a random forest.

I get some results, and can do a classification in MATLAB after training the classifier.
However I'd like to "see" the trees, or want to know how the classification works.

For example, let's run this minimal example, I found here: [Matlab treebagger example](http://kawahara.ca/matlab-treebagger-example/)

So, I end up with a classificator stored in "B".
How can I inspect the trees? Like having a look at each node, to see on which criteria (e.g. feature) the decision is made?
Entering `B` returns:

```
B = 

  TreeBagger
Ensemble with 20 bagged decision trees:
           Training X:                [6x2]
           Training Y:                [6x1]
               Method:       classification
                Nvars:                    2
         NVarToSample:                    2
              MinLeaf:                    1
                FBoot:                    1
SampleWithReplacement:                    1
 ComputeOOBPrediction:                    0
     ComputeOOBVarImp:                    0
            Proximity:                   []
           ClassNames:             '0'             '1'
```

I can't see something like `B.trees` or so.

And a follow-up question would be: 
How to port your random-forest code you prototyped in MATLAB to any other language.
Then you need to know how each tree works, so you can implement it in the target language.

I hope you get the point, or understand my query ;)

Thanks for answers!

Best,
Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out how to inspect the trees, by running the `view()` command. E.g. for inspecting the first tree of the example:

```
>> view(B.Trees{1})
Decision tree for classification
1 if x2<650 then node 2 elseif x2>=650 then node 3 else 0
2 if x1<4.5 then node 4 elseif x1>=4.5 then node 5 else 1
3 class = 0
4 class = 0
5 class = 1
```

By passing some more arguments to the `view()` command, the tree can also be visualized:

```
view(B.Trees{1},'mode','graph')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

to view multiple trees just use loop :

```
for n=1:30 %number of tree
view(t.Trees{n});
end
```

[you can find the source here](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/157290-treebagger-how-do-i-view-entire-tree-or-the-list-of-logical-steps-not-same-as-with-fitctree)